# Implicit Compiling in java

Tags: java

How implicit compiling happens in java?
I am not able to understand the basic difference between implicit compiling and normal compilation of code?
 Also,Do we have have the facility to make our own class object implicit compile?

Comment: You first have to seach about implicit compile and understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit compilation in Java mean that, for example, when compiling a single class Foo.java, the compiler will implicitly compile it dependencies.

You can control the implicit compilation with -implicit parameter associated to the javac command as stated from documentation :

**-implicit:{class,none}
Controls the generation of class files for implicitly loaded source files. To automatically generate class files, use -implicit:class. To suppress class file generation, use -implicit:none. If this option is not specified, the default is to automatically generate class files. In this case, the compiler will issue a warning if any such class files are generated when also doing annotation processing. The warning will not be issued if this option is set explicitly. See Searching For Types.**

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html for more information on java compiler.

Comment: Okay that means we can make our class as implicit compile

Comment: @Jack if you read correctly, by default it automatically generate class files of dependencies. So, by default the value is -implicit:class and you don't have to specify it. It can be useful to use -implicit:none in some case where you don't need to re-build class files which will take less time to the compiler.